# How to read each line from file via redirection?

Tags: c

I'm tryig to read each line from test.txt using redirection. 3 is mode. fopen() is NOT allowed. What argument should I pass to fgets() ???

This is for a Linux server

```
// stdin:     ./main  3  < folder/test.txt

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char str[1000];
  FILE * fp;

  fgets(str, 1000, ???);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 2):

> fopen() is NOT allowed

`fopen()` is not allowed because you get your input from `stdin`. That is, what that command line

> ```
> ./main 3 < folder/test.txt
> ```

does.

It pipes the contents of `test.txt` to your program as `stdin`. You simply read from `stdin` using `fgets()`.

Comment: How do we read from stdin using fgets() ? Is it  fgets(str,1000, fp) ? or fgets(str,1000,stdin) ?

Comment: @cspp37 2nd one

Answer (score 1):

For redirected input, pass `stdin` to `fgets()`.

```
// FILE * fp;  // not needed
if (fgets(str, 1000, stdin)) {
  // Success
}
```